# PHP page routing, working on localhost:3000 but not on localhost/dir/

Tags: php, url-routing

The below code snippet works great when run on **localhost:3000** but stops working when I run it on **localhost/dir/** and for every thing shows the default case result even for a **/**

```
    <?php
    // Grabs the URI and breaks it apart in case we have querystring stuff
    $request_uri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
    // Route it up!
    switch ($request_uri[0]) {
        // Home page
        case '/':
            echo "/ here\n";
            break;
        // About page
        case '/about':
            echo "about.php is opened from here\n";
            break;
        // Everything else
        default:
            header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
            echo "404 is opened from here \n";
            break;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` to see what exactly does it contain.

Comment: In case of **localhost/dir/** Its showing result like ``Array ( [0] => /dir/ )``, so it contains **/dir/**
And in case of **localhost:3000** its showing ``Array ( [0] => / )``, so it contains **/**

Comment: Then it is obvious - in case of `/dir/` You end up in the `default` case.